# Redirect HTTP paths to ports, keeping the rest

Tags: apache-http-server, port, path, http

I have the issue where I want to redirect a URL, like `https://foo.bar/foobar/thing` to `https://foo.bar:1234/thing`. I have seen solutions where one could redirect from `/foobar` to port 1234, but how would I go about trying to create such a reverse proxy rule with the help of apache?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Try e.g.:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName foo.bar

[... other SSL options here]

ProxyPass /foobar/thing http://foo.bar:1234/thing
ProxyPassReverse /foobar/thing http://foo.bar:1234/thing

</VirtualHost>
```

You'll need to have `mod_proxy` enabled and possibly `mod_proxy_html` and `mod_proxy_http`. Note the use of `http:\\` in the destination URL. In the long run, this is (arguably) a simpler approach than trying to using `https:\\`.